# Calling finish() inside onClickListener() of a TextView in SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, simpleadapter

Beginner **Android** and **Java** developer here.

I have this snippet of code inside a **SimpleAdapter** class I use to render a custom list containing a **TextView** and an **ImageView**. This is the part for the **TextView** which processes a URL in another activity.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fromList.length; i++) {
        id = mySimpleAdapter.listMap.get(position).get("id");
        holder.textView[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //How to call finish() here for containing Activity?
                Intent i = new Intent (context, Details.class);
                i.putExtra("url", "http://foo.net/do?id="+id);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

My problem is how to simply call the **finish()** method of the **Activity** that contains this **SimpleAdapter**'s linked **ListView** (to force the **Activity** to reload completely next time it is called).

Thanks to anyone who answers.

Comment: How to adjust this then?

`  this.adapter = new mySimpleAdapter(
    listView.getContext(),
    this.myList, 
    R.layout.updates,
    new String[] { "status" },
    new int[] { R.id.status }
    );

  // set the list's adapter
  listView.setAdapter(this.adapter);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating the `SimpleAdapter`, you should pass it an `Activity` instance instead of `Context`, and then call `finish()` on it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Egor. Thanks for your comment. Is it as simple as

`  public mySimpleAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
  super(context, data, resource, from, to);
  
  // save the ArrayList and context for later usage
  mySimpleAdapter.listMap = data; 
  mySimpleAdapter.context = context;
  mySimpleAdapter.resource = resource;
  mySimpleAdapter.activity = activity;
  
  resourceList = to;
  fromList = from;
 }`

and making other adjustments?

Comment: Context is needed to inflate the layout of the ListView though. And I can't figure out how to do what you suggest.

Comment: @Nono, Activity is a subclass of Context so you can use it instead of Context

Comment: still cannot determine how to adjust `    this.adapter = new mySimpleAdapter( listView.getContext(), this.myList, R.layout.updates, new String[] { "status" }, new int[] { R.id.status } ); // set the list's adapter listView.setAdapter(this.adapter);    `

Comment: @Nono, Instead of listView.getContext() use activity or this if you're inside the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to solve this problem.

First, you should declare an instance of activity

```
private Activity activity;
```

Then, you should "save" an instance of your activity in this variable. Do this inside the **OnCreate** method.

```
activity = this;
```

Then, just call, wherever you want, the function finish()

```
activity.finish();
```

Hope it helped you.